# Ubuntu Budgie - notifications are not clickable

Tags: notification

Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 (new to) here:

the top panel comes with an applet called (I guess) "raven trigger" - that provides a list of notifications (emails, etc). Such notifications are not clickable on my desktop (except that they can be deleted).

Example of a notification that has just come in: "Update for the Tutanota desktop - click here to update": nothing happens when I click there (I have to look for the Tutanova app to update it)...in "Budgie welcome > getting started > customization > desktop settings > top panel" no settings are available for this applet.

any idea?